# Send request repeatedly to the tcp server at regular interval

Tags: go

This is the code taken from the go book. The client enters the message and the request is sent to the server. How to send the same request repeatedly without entering values every time? Also, the time interval between successive requests should be 3 seconds. Should I use goroutines?

```
package main

import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "net"
        "os"

)

func main() {
        arguments := os.Args
        if len(arguments) == 1 {
                fmt.Println("Please provide host:port.")
                return
        }

        CONNECT := arguments[1]
        c, err := net.Dial("tcp", CONNECT)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
         } 

        for {
                reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
                fmt.Print(">>")
                text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

                fmt.Fprintf(c, text+"\n")
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [time.Ticker](https://godoc.org/time#Ticker) to execute code at some specified interval:

```
t := time.NewTicker(3 * time.Second)
defer t.Stop()
for range t.C {
    _, err := c.Write([]byte("Hello!\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZCF7uJzysgz).

Comment: which part exactly? Should I replace a 'for loop'  by the code you suggested?

Comment: Yes.  The code in the answer writes the text "hello" to the connection every three seconds.

Comment: some errors are showing 

./client.go:4:13: imported and not used: "bufio"
./client.go:25:9: undefined: time
./client.go:30:4: undefined: log

Comment: I removed bufio, added time and log in the import part. it's working but the server is not getting that hello message

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/ZCF7uJzysgz for a working example of the 3 second loop.

Comment: why the server is not getting the hello message?, any idea?

Comment: let me try the one you suggested. Thank you

Comment: @kool As the playground example demonstrates, the client writes data to the connection every three seconds.  It's impossible for me to diagnose the problem with the server because the question contains no information about the server.

Comment: Please check the server part here. the server should get the message, saves it in a slice and replies with a hello message too. https://play.golang.org/p/XDlWuhYYHM5

Comment: The server expects \n delimited messages.  Terminate each message with a \n.